# ColumnsDirective's columns values not showing when columns are being added dynamically

Tags: reactjs, syncfusion, gantt-chart

I need to show **ColumnsDirective** dynamically based on the user selection among many fields which may be not only the standard ones that the **GanttComponent** use as those shown in the Get started documentation:

```
this.taskFields = {
        id: 'TaskID',
        name: 'TaskName',
        startDate: 'StartDate',
        duration: 'Duration',
        progress: 'Progress',
        child: 'subtasks',
    };
```

When those other fields are included among **ColumnsDirective** on the initial **GanttComponent** display, values on the columns cells will show 
[image]

but when those fields are added dynamically later on after the initial display their values won't show in their columns cells.

Here is a [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-6lscfc-kbe4mv) showing the issue ([screenshot](https://i.imgur.com/AJGHpvC.gifv))

I tried predefine those columns in the taskFields initially even before their dynamic add in **ColumnsDirective** but that didn't solve the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of refreshing the whole Gantt, we recommend you to change the column visibility dynamically by using showColumn and hideColumn public  method.

```
<button type="button" onClick={ev => { 
   if (this.ganttInstance.getGridColumns()[2].visible) { 
     this.ganttInstance.hideColumn('fieldXX1'); 
   } 
   else { 
      this.ganttInstance.showColumn('fieldXX1'); 
   } 
}}>Change Comlumns</button>
```

Sample - https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-6lscfc-yqzk6h?file=index.js

We have also provided solution, for refreshing the whole gantt using refresh method.

```
<button type="button" onClick={ev => { 
       //... 
  setTimeout(function () { 
    var obj = document.getElementById('Default').ej2_instances[0]; 
      obj.refresh(); 
  }, 100); 
}}>Change Columns</button>
```

Sample - https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-6lscfc-n3xgjh?file=index.js